# How does a Genesis child theme understand that the Genesis theme is the parent theme?

Tags: child-theme, genesis-theme-framework

In most Genesis child themes, the following line of code exists:

```
// Starts the engine.
require_once get_template_directory() . '/lib/init.php';
```

I understand that this includes the init.php file from the lib directory within the Genesis parent theme folder.

My question is simply - why does `get_template_directory()` return the Genesis parent folder, as opposed to the child theme folder? And how does it identify it if there are multiple parent themes possible?

Comment: Is there any reason you think it's anything other than the way any other child theme works? https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not experienced with Genesis, specifically, but I imagine its child themes work the same as child themes for any other theme. [As documented](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/), a child theme is created by adding a `Template:` line to the style.css header, which is the directory name of the parent theme:

```
/*
 Theme Name: Genesis Child Theme
 Template: genesis
*/
```

By defining the "Template" for a theme, WordPress functions like `get_template_directory()` know to use that theme's directory for the path or URL.

Answer (score -1):

There is no multiple parent theme possible. Because you specify parent theme by Template: genesis. This helps WordPress to find parent theme.